# Removing all prime factors less than n from a number

Tags: factorization

Is there an efficient way to check a number x and remove all prime factors in the number which are less than some n?  For example for n = 200:

```
x=88984589931961415442566827779929187431222364934742868664124547963532933

FactorInteger[x]

{{29, 2}, {31, 1}, {37, 2}, {269, 1}, {271, 
  1}, {34200471605536976187361939984030218061598132568100785528233, 
  1}}
```

After removing all prime factors < n from x gives:

```
2493180179572040027082498062895818866472442266081979164222657467
```

I'd like to use as large n as possible and then use PrimeQ to check the remaining number, which is faster than checking for large prime factors.

I made this code which works but may be slow:

```
x=2*53*6571*18313*31259

n=20000;
n=PrimePi[n];
listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved={};
AppendTo[listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved,x];
For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
z=Last[listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved];
a=IntegerExponent[z,Prime[i]];
z=z/(Prime[i]^a);
AppendTo[listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved,z];
]
CountDistinct[listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved]-1 (*count of how many prime factors were removed*)

Last[listWithSmallPrimeFactorsRemoved] (*the remaining number after removing prime factors \[LessEqual] n*)
```

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: The combination of `For` and `AppendTo` is a good indicator for bad code in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasteful but works:

```
x = 88984589931961415442566827779929187431222364934742868664124547963532933;
n = 200;

FixedPoint[Numerator[#/n!] &, x]

(*    2493180179572040027082498062895818866472442266081979164222657467    *)
```

A bit less wasteful (Thanks @evanb!): only use prime factors,

```
A = Times @@ Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]];
FixedPoint[Numerator[#/A] &, x]

(*    2493180179572040027082498062895818866472442266081979164222657467    *)
```

Or a bit more direct but much slower:

```
y = x;
Do[While[Divisible[y, i], y /= i], {i, 2, n}];
y

(*    2493180179572040027082498062895818866472442266081979164222657467    *)
```

Comment: You can accelerate the loop by just iterating over primes:

  `y = x;
i = 2;
While[
  i <= n,
  While[Divisible[y, i], y /= i];
  i = NextPrime[i]
  ];`

Answer (score 1):

Select should help you in this case:

```
n=200;

Select[FactorInteger[x], #[[1]] > n &]
```

> {{269, 1}, {271, 
>     1},{34200471605536976187361939984030218061598132568100785528233, 
>     1}}

Comment: Hi, I will edit the question to be more clear, I actually don't need to factor the remaining number, only PrimeQ it.